# Docker django runs server but browser doesn't show landing page

Tags: django, docker

I have successfully build docker and the server runs without error but when I browse the website it doesn't show anything.

Here are the configuration files I'm using:

`.env.dev`

```
DEBUG=1
SECRET_KEY=foo
DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS=localhost 127.0.0.1 [::1]
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.9.1-slim-buster

# set working directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# set environment variables
ENV PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE 1
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# install dependencies
RUN pip install --upgrade pip
COPY ./requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
COPY . .
```

`docker-compose.yml`

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  movies:
    build: ./app
    command: python core/manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./app/:/usr/src/app/
    ports:
      - 8009:8000
    env_file:
      - ./app/.env.dev
```

Any idea why it isn't browsing?

Comment: Have you tried changing the DJANGO_ALLOWED_HOSTS to 0.0.0.0 ?

Comment: Thanks. It is working. Whitenoise in the django admin is not loading but the server is working properly

Comment: I'll explain in an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` as allowed hosts, you refer to the container, not the host machine. So, even if you link the ports of the container to those of the host, the server will not accept the connections since they are not coming from the container IP.